# Marker in MapView disappears after rotating it

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-maps-markers

```
public Drawable rotateDrawable(int angle)
{
    Bitmap arrowBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.arrowscalled);

    // Create blank bitmap of equal size
    Bitmap canvasBitmap = arrowBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    canvasBitmap.eraseColor(0x00000000);

   // Create canvas
   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);

   // Create rotation matrix
   Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
   rotateMatrix.setRotate(angle, canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2);

   // Draw bitmap onto canvas using matrix
   canvas.drawBitmap(arrowBitmap, rotateMatrix, null);

   return new BitmapDrawable(canvasBitmap);
}
```

Whenever I call this the marker dissapears instead of rotating. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The extra canvas (canvasBitmap) is confusing me, why have it at all?

Comment: Can you format the code better using the nice tools SO give us!

Comment: @Dan it was for something else, either way it is not the problem I have removed it thank you for reminding me.

Comment: Is the goal to show this in a ImageView or draw it directly on a canvas?

Comment: @Dan Draw directly on the canvas using setMarker(Drawable d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of going through the hassle of creating a new Canvas and all that use [Bitmap.createBitmap (Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height, Matrix m, boolean filter)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20boolean%29). When you create your rotation matrix, use half the width and height passed to the createBitmap function. After this create your BitmapDrawable.